# How do I calculate the thrust needed in a rocket to reach a certain acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, rocket-science

I have recently been studying basic rocket science and I have been trying to figure out by searching online for tutorials on this particular matter and I have not found anything. The problem I am having is I don't know how to calculate how much **thrust power** I need to reach a certain acceleration.

Let's say I have a rocket. This rocket has a **mass of 2,5 kg**. It's **weight is 24,5 N**, I want it to accelerate with a speed of **2 m/s^2**.

How do I calculate that, **formulas** would be appreciated as I **don't want cheats**, only help.

Comment: Pretty much anything useful you do with rockets requires you to consider what kind of fuel you are using. At a minimum, you need to know the specific impulse of the fuel.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Are you confident enough that this is a homework problem to drop the mod-hammer?  To me it looks like a budding rocket scientist who is looking for the correct equations and has grasped the wrong ones.  It seems certainly worth *asking* whether it is homework first.

Comment: @CortAmmon I'm not sure what you mean - our homework policy applies regardless of whether or not the question is *actual* homework, and just asking for the formulae needed to compute a particular quantity *does* clearly fall under the HW policy.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I'm not sure where in that policy asking for formulae falls under HW.  I do see the summary states "As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on"  I can say from personal experience that I, as someone who played Kerbal Space Program, would have *loved* to come across an answer which points to the right rocket equations.

Comment: @CortAmmon He's basically asking for a formula to plug all this information into.  He didn't really ask about the related concepts.  I think you could also make a case for this being "too broad" or even "unclear what you're asking"; because we know nothing about this rocket besides it's "mass", which may or may not include a fuel estimate.

Comment: @ACuriousMind This wasn't homework, this was just something I decided to start learning about. By studying I didn't mean as a subject in school, I meant it as simply studying by myself

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is really straightforward:  F=MA.  You have a mass of 2.5kg, and want a 2m/s^2 acceleration, so the force you need is straightforward to find.

However, in reality, that equation isn't all that useful.  The acceleration is going to change as the mass of the rocket decreases (you're burning propellant!).  Rocketeers aren't as worried about accelerations as they are about the total change in velocity that the rocket undergoes.

For that, you will want [Tsiolkovsky's Rocket Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation).

$$\Delta V=v_e\ln\frac{m_0}{m_f}$$

Where $m_0$ is the starting mass (propellant and all), and $m_f$ is the final mass (which is just the dry mass, after all the propellant is gone).  $v_e$ is the effective exhaust velocity, which is a property of your engine and your fuel.  It is related to the specific impulse (Isp), $v_e=I_{sp}g_0$ where $g_0$ is the acceleration of gravity at sea level.